# Erro no foreach - Notice: Array to string conversion in

Tags: php, html

Estou com dificuldade na hora de gerar um tabela usando o foreach, inicialmente estou tentando colocar para que apareça o numero do campo ID da tabela animal na tabela, mas fica aparecendo o erro: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Users\Ulisses\Desktop\usbwebserver- TCCc\root\SGS\animais_cadastrados.php on line 196

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome do Documento</th>
      <th>Codigo de Identificação</th>
      <th>Alterar</th>
      <th>Excluir</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <?php 

include"cone.php";

$sql="SELECT *FROM animal";

$dados = $conn->query($sql);
$rows = $dados->fetch_assoc();

foreach($rows as $key => $value) { ?>


    <tr>
      <a>
        <th scope="row">
          <a href="#" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> PDF </a>
        </th>
        <td>
          <?php echo $value.["id_animal"] ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="editar_animal.php">
            <i class="fa fa-edit" style="color: green; font-size: 20px;">
                                    </i>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="excluir_animal.php">
            <i class="fa fa-times" style="color: red; font-size: 20px;">
                                    </i>
        </td>

        </a>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <?php } ?>

</table>
```

[image: Imagem do tabela do banco de dados]

Answer (score 1):

Troca seu `<?php echo $value.["id_animal"] ?>` por `<?php echo $value["id_animal"] ?>` e tenta

Comment: já tentei isso.. é não foi